# how to extract column name and type from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `external_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `street_address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `suburb` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
...
)
```

I want to get the columns and type as single column  `Name : Type,` like this :

```
orders_id:int(11),
external_id:bigint(20),
id:int(11),
...
```

It should be something like:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_schema' AND TABLE_NAME = 'orders';
```

I'm not sure how I get the type and how I convert it to my desired output

Comment: You might start with `describe orders`;. Your format requirement implies other processing components which you;ve not told us anything about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below query

```
SELECT SELECT concat(concat(concat(column_name,':'),data_type),',') as columnval
FROM information_schema.columns where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_schema' AND TABLE_NAME = 'orders'
```

EDIT:  (by gordon)

If the above is sort-of correct, it should be written as:

```
SELECT concat(column_name, ':' data_type ',') as columnval
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_schema' AND TABLE_NAME = 'orders';
```

Comment: It shows the column and type along with other things that I don't need.. and it's not in the desired format

Comment: modified my answer you can check now

Answer (score 1):

Use this request :

```
SELECT
    concat(COLUMN_NAME, ':', DATA_TYPE, IF(NUMERIC_PRECISION, CONCAT('(', NUMERIC_PRECISION, ')'), IF(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, CONCAT('(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ')'), ''))) as name
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
```

Result :

```
+----------------------+
| name                 |
+----------------------+
| id:int(10)           |
| co_id:int(10)        |
| EVP_type:varchar(255)|
| date:date            |
+----------------------+
```